# Write a function that accepts an integer as an argument, and returns a boolean.

Tags: java, python

This is an interview question:

1. Write a function that accepts an integer as an argument, and returns a boolean. The returned boolean is true if the integer is an exponential (power) of two, false otherwise.
   a. No math libraries or bitwise operations, only + - * / %
   b. 1 is the zeroth power of two.
   c. No floats, so no "negative powers."
   d. Non-powers should generally be identified faster than powers.
   e. Any language, though general overlap with desired position is wise.

I am really rough on booleans as I haven't taken my Java class in a year or so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where will you use python in this question? What have you tried?

Comment: have you tried using using google?  http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap05_07.html looks like it would teach you almost all of this and is the 7th result for `java function return boolean`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely be checking out that link.

Comment: Wait, "any language"… so I can write a language where `n % 2` gives me the answer in a single step, can't I? (And yeah, I'm pretty sure I could write the interpreter for that language in a few minutes… although it might end up being `(% n 2)` or `n 2 %` instead of infix…)

Comment: I don't mean to hijack the post, but interesting question for someone preparing for interviews in the future. But " d. Non-powers should generally be identified faster than powers." I don't understand this requirement. Explain? thanks

Comment: @CppLearner: That's because they have a specific implementation in mind—the one posted by Tim, which divides and checks for odd at each step, rather than multiplying and checking for overflow at the end. It has the same worst-case behavior, but better average-case and best-case. They don't want to hire anyone who can't figure out this optimization (but apparently they don't mind hiring people who don't suspect that division might be an order of magnitude slower than multiplication).

Answer (score 4):

The best way to meet all 4 requirements is to keep halving `n` until it is odd or 1.

```
def ispow(n):
    while True:
        if n == 1:
            return True
        if n % 2 == 1:
            return False
        n = n / 2
```

Output:

```
1 True
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 True
9 False
10 False
```

Comment: @smaccoun: This and mgilson's are both O(log2 N). The best-case here is obviously better (since you can rule out, e.g., `9` with only 1 step instead of 4), but the worst-case is identical.

Comment: @smaccoun: However, I misread the question: "d. Non-powers should generally be identified faster than powers." This implies that if you handed over mgilson's solution they'd tell you that the best-case behavior isn't good enough…

Comment: From a quick test, it looks like the old-skool C optimization of replacing the `n % 2 == 1` with `n & 1` and `n = n / 2` with `n >>= 1` makes a huge difference in performance here. Of course that violates requirement a, but I'd argue it with the interviewer if it were me…

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer is clearly the one the interviewers are looking for.

However, you can do much better by breaking the rules:

> d. Non-powers should generally be identified faster than powers.

As BoppreH points out, an answer which counts upward rather than downward is going to be much faster (at least with most languages and platforms) because there's no division. His implementation is nearly an order of magnitude faster than Tim's for the worst case.

Of course BoppreH's average case and best case are basically the same as the worst case, while in Tim's the best case is much better. But often worst case is very important, so that's certainly a tradeoff worth examining.

Or:

> a. No math libraries or bitwise operations, only + - * / %

The slow part of Tim's solution is the division operators, but really, they're not necessary. You can replace `n % 2 == 1` with `n & 1`, and `n = n / 2` with `n = n >> 1`, which are guaranteed to be equivalent, and suddenly the worst case is an order of magnitude faster—faster even than BoppreH's.

This is the kind of thing you might expect the compiler to do for you in, say, C (then again, try dealing with `2**100000` without math libraries in C…), but in Python (at least CPython—it's probably worth trying PyPy, and maybe Jython and IronPython), you have to do it manually. And you should be allowed to.

And this is why these kinds of interview questions are stupid and pointless, except for as a jumping-off point for further discussion. The answer they're clearly looking for is very often not the answer you'd want to use in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter and executes only a multiplication each iteration.

```
def is_power(x):
    current_power = 1
    while current_power < x:
        current_power *= 2
    return current_power == x
```

Benchmark for x = 2 ^ 100.000

```
number = str(2 ** 100000)
cProfile.run('is_power(' + number + ')')
cProfile.run('ispow(' + number + ')')
cProfile.run('is_pow_2(' + number + ')')
```

- is_power (this): 1.264 seconds
- [ispow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465598/252218) (Tim's answer): 11.455 seconds

The other hasn't finished yet...

Comment: Um… `2 ^ 100.000` is a `TypeError`. And if you meant `2 ^ 100000`, that's just `100002`. Which raises the question of whether your test was accurate…

Comment: The actual test was using `2 ** 100000`. I wrote as 2 ^ 100.000 for clarity. I'm adding the benchmark code to the answer.

Comment: This doesn't meet part d of the question.

Comment: This is actually interesting. It clearly does _not_ meet the requirement that "Non-powers should generally be identified faster than powers", but if that's only true because you handle powers as fast as they expected you to handle non-powers, instead of because you handle non-powers as slow as they expected you to handle powers, is that acceptable?

Comment: The speed depends on how "non-power" the number is. For 2^100.000 + 1, Tim's answer completes instantly, while mine takes the full second. But for 2^100.000 * 3, the results are the same for the real powers: just above a second for mine, and just above 11 second for Tim's.

Comment: If you were allowed to use `&` and `>>=`, Tim's solution is faster than yours even for powers (I get 0.356s for yours, 4.507s for Tim's unmodified, 0.316s for Tim's modified), and of course his gets better the "odder" you get. I suppose the right answer is to show them that Tim's is the one they were expecting, but then show both different ways to improve it by breaking the rules (d in your case, a in the case of the modified-Tim answer).

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, use force:

```
def is_pow_2(x):
    i=0
    while 2**i <= x:
        if x == 2**i:
           return True
        i += 1
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout

```
import re
n = 2**5
print   bool(re.match("^10*$",bin(n)[2:]))
```